# ASP.NET Core Image upload POST request to API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, imgur

I'm new to ASP.NET Core and i am trying to make a POST request to the "**Imgbb API**" and upload a picture and get the upload link in response, (because imgbb seems simpler to me than imgur that requires authorization and other things, so I chose imgbb) so far this is what i have:

Select file in front-end:

```
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label class="control-label">Profile Picture</label>
                <input type="file" name="ProfilePic" class="form-control" />
            </div>
```

And in my Controller method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IFormFile Image)
        {
            try
            {
                var file = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files["ProfilePic"];
                if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
                {
                    //file arrived here
                    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
                        .Create("https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?expiration=0&key=73f2f1704ea84f87c7b1ce13180b2be0"); //API key at the end
                    webRequest.Method = "POST";

                    Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
                    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(ms);
                        var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                }
```

The example call in Javascript is confusing me:

```
curl --location --request POST "https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?expiration=600&key=YOUR_CLIENT_API_KEY" --form "image=R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
```

I know this code is not good but, this is how far I have gone after hundreds of searches so far I have not found any example like this on **ASP.NET**, I have done it in Javascript but on ASP.NET seems very complicated to me, please someone who has an example, e.g **Imgur** or any other web image hosting to share it, or any instruction that the image should be (byte array) or something or the steps to be done, I would be very grateful.

Comment: May this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60809635/how-to-upload-an-image-to-imgbb-api-using-javascript-in-a-firefox-addon) is helpful.