# Uploading images using AJAX + Javascript to IMGBB on PHP website (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Currently i have a simple form that lets users put the URL of an image (hosted elsewhere) on my website:

```
<input type="text" name="food_img" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Image URL">
```

Now i want to integrate an image upload function using a third party (ImgBB), maintaining the text field, in case the user still want to host the images manually elsewhere.

I have found another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60809635/how-to-upload-an-image-to-imgbb-api-using-javascript-in-a-firefox-addon) with the code to do so, but im unable to make it work on my bootstrap website:

HTML:

```
            <input type="text" name="food_img" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Image URL">
            <input type="file" id="input_img" onchange="fileChange()" accept="image/*">
```

Javascript:

```
function fileChange(){
        var file = document.getElementById('input_img');
        var form = new FormData();
        form.append("image", file.files[0])

        var settings = {
          "url": "https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=8d5867a9512390fb5e5dc97839aa36f6",
          "method": "POST",
          "timeout": 0,
          "processData": false,
          "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
          "contentType": false,
          "data": form
        };

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
          var jx = JSON.parse(response);
          console.log(jx.data.url);
        });
        }
```

With the above code, i can see on the browser console that the image is correctly uploaded to the service:

```
Empty string passed to getElementById(). 2 file.html
{"data":{"id":"D7HDrf6","title":"24","url_viewer":"https:\/\/ibb.co\/D7HDrf6","url":"https:\/\/i.ibb.co\/309yRm8\/24.jpg","display_url":"https:\/\/i.ibb.co\/309yRm8\/24.jpg","size":66579,"time":"1614194220","expiration":"0","image":{"filename":"24.jpg","name":"24","mime":"image\/jpeg","extension":"jpg","url":"https:\/\/i.ibb.co\/309yRm8\/24.jpg"},"thumb":{"filename":"24.jpg","name":"24","mime":"image\/jpeg","extension":"jpg","url":"https:\/\/i.ibb.co\/D7HDrf6\/24.jpg"},"delete_url":"https:\/\/ibb.co\/D7HDrf6\/71f82327d25ce6fa7447aeb72ca8065b"},"success":true,"status":200} file.html:77:11
https://i.ibb.co/309yRm8/24.jpg
```

But i'm unable to "paste" the image URL to the corresponding field, before submitting the form. Also, i am trying to make this work on several  fields on the same form (so that users can put, for example, footer, header and profile pictures), but i see that the javascript code applies to only one ID. Is it possible to make it work on multiple IDs without duplicating the JS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like console.log(jx.data.url); returns the correct url, right?

(https://i.ibb.co/309yRm8/24.jpg)

The next step is "paste" this url to the Form Input Element, and you can do that with vanilla JS or jQuery, for example:

$('input[name="food_img"]').val(jx.data.url);

I would try this string after console log, then with "inspect" to see if the form is correctly "completed".

Best, Smith

Comment: oh, didn't specified, you can easily make jQuery work on your webpage using https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: Correct, the console log returns the correct image URL, in that case 24.jpg. It also returns other sizes ant the delete URL, but i dont need those for my specific application. Thanks, will try your solution

Comment: It works! thanks alot. Do you know a way to do this to more than one input group on the same form, without repeating the code? (for example, input name=background_image, etc.)